# poor quality of the pictures from the camera(android)

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

Sorry for my english. I get image from camera, but i have bad quality image from camera. Bellow my code:

```
 Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

                    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                    FileOutputStream fo;
                    try {
                        destination.createNewFile();
                        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                        fo.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get image from camera, but i have bad quality image from camera.

Apparently, you are not including `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `Intent`, and therefore you are only getting the thumbnail. Quoting [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.